# Where is kCCKeySizeAES128? kCCEncrypt?... Common Crypto?

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, aes, commoncrypto

Where is kCCKeySizeAES128? kCCEncrypt?

I found "Common Crypto Framework" by searching kCCKeySizeAES128, in iOS dev. lib..

But my MacBook does not have "Common Crypto Framework".

Help me... I need to use kCCKeySizeAES128 and kCCEncrypt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#import <CommonCrypto/~~~.h>
```

Just Import framework.

Adding framework does not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Common Crypto is not its own framework.  It's built into libSystem.  The headers you need are in /usr/include/CommonCrypto, which you can import by doing

```
#import <CommonCrypto/~~~.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, it's defined in *CommonCryptor.h*. You should `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>`